# What does "plus changing existing physical trait allocations" mean on a Variable Power?

Tags: powers, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

I'm studying some stat blocks from both the M&M 3E Forums and the DC Heroes and Villains Vol. 1 and 2, and I find many shapeshifter themed powers using Variable have "plus changing existing physical trait allocations" on the statblock, an example being Gold's Shapeshifting Power.

> #### Shapeshifting
>
> - Elongation 8; Morph 4 (any form)
> - Quirk: Limited to Same Color
> - Variable 2 (physical traits, 10 power points, plus changing existing
>   physical trait allocations)

I can't find any extra on the power or modifiers that tell me what they mean by that.

Comment: @AldathLeCarde:
Is there anything more I can add to my answer to better help you?

Comment: I liked it, was really helpfil. I would add, however, that Shapeshift is an example power found on an "Under the Cloak" segment of Hero's Handbook, thus its unique rulling can only be found there :)

Comment: Looks like it's a sample power in all of the books, so you're pretty much in the clear. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally, the **Shapeshift** power let you take points out of Strength, Dexterity, etc, to transfer to powers so that, e.g. your Housecat form wouldn't be as strong as a human. It's up to the GM to decide exactly which traits to allow and how far to reduce the stats.

You can find the **[Shapeshift](http://www.d20herosrd.com/6-powers/effects/sample-powers/shapeshift)** power description in all of the core rulebooks as a Sample Power built from the base power of **Variable**. The description is as follows (emphasis mine):

> You can transform into different forms, gaining the physical traits (abilities, skills, advantages, and powers) of the assumed form. You gain (Shapeshift rank x 5) character points worth of traits. **You can also redistribute points spent on your own physical traits (lowering your Strength to apply those points elsewhere, for example)**. You are limited to the inherent traits of the forms you assume and do not gain new mental traits, even if that form possesses them.

As a side note, Shapeshift does not, in and of itself, include any sort of **Morph** effect so that you change appearance. That's considered entirely up to GM purview as to whether you make your players spend points to not be recognizable when they Shapeshift. Personally, I think that it falls under the "no one recognizes Superman as Clark Kent" situation and they just don't get the ability to look like a particular cat, pangolin, or xenomorph when they change shape.